# animation-list error en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy intentando realizar un fondo animado para la aplicación.
Lo que quiero hacer es una fondo degradado en dos colores, pero al ver que con shapes en xml no me dejaba hacerlo como yo queria he tenido que realizar un "animation-list" e incluir imagenes.

Ahora, el problema es el siguiente, la animación se compone de 65 imagenes que estan dentro del "animation-list" como en el siguiente código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg1" android:duration="1" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg2" android:duration="1" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg3" android:duration="1" />
...
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg65" android:duration="1" />
</animation-list>
```

Principalmente en el código no me muestra ningún error, pero a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación me da error en la parte donde aplica el layout.
Como en el layout tengo en "FrameLayout" puesto como backgraund esta animation-list.

Despues probando mire que no da ningun problema hasta los 6 items, pero a partir del septimo me da el fallo.

¿Alguien sabe si animation-list tiene un limite de items? o ¿Me falta poner algo?.

PD: A la hora de ejecutar el codigo, yo lo incluyo en el `onCreate();` (No se si es correcto).

El error en el logCat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: etbapps.com.miconsejero, PID: 24809
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{etbapps.com.miconsejero/etbapps.com.miconsejero.index}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML
>   file line #2: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:
>   Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
>                                                                                at etbapps.com.miconsejero.index.onCreate(index.java:17)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:
>   Error inflating class 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
>                                                                                at etbapps.com.miconsejero.index.onCreate(index.java:17) 
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
>                                                                                at etbapps.com.miconsejero.index.onCreate(index.java:17) 
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9437196
>   byte allocation with 482800 free bytes and 471KB until OOM
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
>                                                                                at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
>                                                                                at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
>                                                                                at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
>                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
>                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
>                                                                                at
>   android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimationDrawable.java:324)
>                                                                                at
>   android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:294)
>                                                                                at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
>                                                                                at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)
>                                                                                at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2630)
>                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
>                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.(View.java:3948)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:573)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:97)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:92)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:88)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
>                                                                                at etbapps.com.miconsejero.index.onCreate(index.java:17) 
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

mi layout es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/index_bg"> 
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/etbapps_logo" android:id="@+id/logo"/> 
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Tito! es importante agregues el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat para encontrar cual es el error con exactitud.

Comment: Gracias!, Si revisas los mensajes en el LogCat te hará más fácil la vida al desarrollar aplicaciones Android. El problema ocurre al inflar una vista, Cual es el layout que cargas dentro de onCreateView() con setContentView( ??? ) ?.

Comment: en "setContentView" pongo el layout que le he creado "R.layout.activity_layout" en el tengo un "FrameLayout" en el que establezco como background esta animation-list.

Comment: Agrega por favor el layout que carga tu actividad "index"; Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{etbapps.com.miconsejero/etbapps.com.miconsejero.index}: . El problema esta en ese layout...

Comment: @Elenasys, esto es lo que tiene el layout.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/index_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/etbapps_logo"
        android:id="@+id/logo"/>

</FrameLayout>

Comment: El error se encuentra en el layout, revisa mi respuesta!, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el layout que carga tu actividad `index.java`, lo puedes ver en el mensaje de error, indica además que el error ocurre al inflar el layout en la línea #2:

> etbapps.com.miconsejero/etbapps.com.miconsejero.index}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML
>   file line #2: Error inflating class at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at

Revisando el Layout, encontramos el error al definir el `namespace` del `FrameLayout` :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
```

Los `namespaces` deben terminar con ";"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/index_bg"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/etbapps_logo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys, pero no se como se ha colado ese ";" en el copy/paste, realmente no lo tengo en el layout, y estoy un poco desesperado porque no consigo hacerlo funcionar ;(

Comment: Pues al colocarle ese ' ; ' al final del namespace me da error.

Comment: A perdón, en ese caso sin el ' ; ' me sigue dando error. Exactamente el mismo error del principio.
Según e leido en algunos hilos, no se puede establecer un animation-list en el onCreate(), pero tampoco encuentro otra solución ;(

Comment: Uff @Elenasys, no me estoy enterando muy bien. En el ejemplo que me has puesto arriba no lleva ' ; ' y ahora me dices que si lo debo poner, en cualquier caso con o sin no funciona.

Comment: Ok, osea, según me pones xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";  <-- Debe llevar ese punto y coma, pero no puedo hacer eso porque me da error de "invalid token"

Comment: Ok, veo que lo que quieres decir es que NO debe ir el punto y coma, en cualquier caso, sea lo que sea, con punto y coma o sin punto y coma, no funciona

Comment: TITO! el problema es cuando lo pego aquí, copialo tal y como esta en mi respuesta! sin ";" y con http://